# Won't show the validation message

Tags: c#

When the user enters nothing, the error message does not display. It just does nothing. Have I put the else message in the wrong place?

```js
  private void btnLogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            if (txtLogin2.Text != "" && txtPassword2.Text != "")
            {
                int AID = Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin2.Text);
                Entities2 db = new Entities2();
                Administrator admin = db.Administrators.Where(x => x.AID == AID && x.Password == txtPassword2.Text).SingleOrDefault();
                if (admin != null)
                {
                    Admin admini = new Admin();
                    admini.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    int value;
                    if (int.TryParse(txtLogin2.Text, out value)) {
                        MessageBox.Show("User ID not in valid format");
                    }
                    if (txtLogin2.Text == "" )
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a User ID");
                    }
                    if (txtPassword2.Text == "") {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Password");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the user enters nothing

Then the first `if` statement evaluates to false:

```
if (txtLogin2.Text != "" && txtPassword2.Text != "")
```

Which means none of the code in this function would be reached.  You probably want to put these at the start of the function:

```
if (txtLogin2.Text == "" )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a User ID");
}
if (txtPassword2.Text == "") {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Password");
}
if (txtLogin2.Text != "" && txtPassword2.Text != "")
{
    //... the rest of the code, minus the if statements above
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply your else is in the wrong place, you're entering the checking if both textbox are not empty. try adding a checking and rearrange like below.

```js
  private void btnLogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int value;
            if (int.TryParse(txtLogin2.Text, out value)) {
                        MessageBox.Show("User ID not in valid format");
            }
            if (txtLogin2.Text == "" )
            {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a User ID");
            }
            if (txtPassword2.Text == "") {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Password");
            }
                int AID = Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin2.Text);
                Entities2 db = new Entities2();
                Administrator admin = db.Administrators.Where(x => x.AID == AID && x.Password == txtPassword2.Text).SingleOrDefault();
                if (admin != null)
                {
                    Admin admini = new Admin();
                    admini.ShowDialog();
                }
        }
```